# Return more than just one value with jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, api, autocomplete, spotify

I'm trying to return the track "href" value from the spotify api using the jQuery autocomplete widget. Here is my code:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#spotify_song_search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json", {
                q: request.term
            }, function(data) {
                response($.map(data.tracks, function(el, ui) {
                    return el.name;
                }));
            });
        },
        select: function(el, ui) {
            alert(ui.item.href);
        }
    });
});​
```

URL to response: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=time

In it's current state it alerts `[object Object]`. What do I need to do to return the href value?

Comment: could you paste the response?

Comment: here is the url to the response: http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=time

Comment: sorry, make sure that its the json link

Comment: Why not just log it and see what's in the object?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how to do that lol I'll do a google search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/MMPTC/

```
   $(function() {
    $("#spotify_song_search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json", {
                q: request.term
            }, function(data) {
                response($.map(data.tracks, function(item) {
                    return {label: item.name, track: item};
                }));
            });
        },
        select: function(el, ui) {
                console.log(ui);
            $("#track").attr("href",ui.item.track.href).text("Listen");
        }
    });
});​

<input type="text" id="spotify_song_search">
<a id='track'></a>​
```

P.S. The fact that this amount of code actually lets me search for tracks and actually play them, just blew my mind. The internet is...AWESOME. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example I use, I return a few values on my call to use elsewhere on the page

```
$("#SearchField").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = request.term;
        if (term in entityCache) {
            response(entityCache[term]);
            return;
        }
        if (entitiesXhr != null) {
            entitiesXhr.abort();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            data: request,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item.SchoolName, value: item.EntityName, id: item.EntityID, code: item.EntityCode };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, result) {
        $("#EntityID").val(result.item.id);
        $("#Code").val(result.item.code);
    }
});
```

It has a caching mechanism as well :-)